# Perl regex specifying maximum length for capture

Tags: regex, perl

I have an regex like this in Perl:

```
\s{2,}(?<name>(\S+\s)*\S+)\s{2,}
```

Is there a way that I can verify the length of the named capture `$+{name}` inside the regex?

I want to match only the values with a maximum provided length.

For example, I want `$+{name}` to be a maximum of 27 characters.

I think that this case can be done using lookarounds, but I am not that familiar with this method yet.

Here is an example:

I have this data:

```
ROTINSON, JABON                                          0.000
CHUNG, TSONH-HIW                                                           0.000
ROBINSONS, VISTOR R                                                                 0.000
```

The names that you can see will be matched by ((\S+\s)*\S+), and I want my regexp to catch if possible exactly 27 characters, because I think that is the maximum length the column will need.

The numbers that you see should be in different columns, and I want to find exactly which value must be added in one column and so on. This file is not a fixed width file, so not all the values will be separated exactly by the same number of spaces. There will be some small variations.

Until now I used this for my match, but is not working as I want to:

```
/^\s{0,8}(?P<name>(\S+\s){0,5}\S+)
\s{10,70}(?P<value>\d+\.\d+)
\s*$/xi
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `$+{name}` means... do you mean a name? And does the max 27 length include spaces?

Comment: Please don't use html code in the Markup code.

Comment: @Jerry: `@+` is an array that  `holds the offsets of the ends of the last successful submatches` see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks :) @M42 I'm not sure where you got `@+`, I said `$+` xP But it's okay, I found it on the doc page as well.

Comment: @M42 That's not an array, that is a hash, and the hash is `%+`. The variable is called `%LAST_PAREN_MATCH`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to reject matches where the named capture exceeds 27 characters, or that you want only the first 27 characters of any such capture?

Comment: Are you sure that using this kind of regex is the best way to parse your input? It feels very arbitrary to me, and it sounds like an attempt to parse csv data, in which case, this is a very poor way to do it.

Comment: I want to reject matches where the named capture exceeds 27 characters.

Comment: @SebastianStrajan You should show some sample input, name your constraints and expected output.

Comment: I want to extract the data from an txt file created from a pdf file using the unix command pdftotext -layout file1.pdf file1.out, and in the end I want all the data into a csv file...

Comment: @SebastianStrajan That is helpful information. The reason I ask is because this is an XY-problem, in all likelihood. Meaning that you are attempting a solution which is not the best.

Comment: @TLP: Yes you're rigth, I mixed `@+` and `%+`.

Comment: @TLP I added more info about it

Comment: @SebastianStrajan The data you are showing has 3 "columns" (assuming that is spaces and not tabs), not 27. And also, did I not ask you please not to add html code in the question? Use Markup, its what its there for.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am not used with the formatting. There are 4 columns, and the number 27 is for the maximum length of the name capture...

Comment: @SebastianStrajan Do you have to put all of this logic into a regex? You know you could do something like `if (/^(\S+\s\S+)/ and length($1) == 27) `. Also, if this is a fixed width string, you can simply read 27 characters in a variety of different ways: `substr($str, 0, 27)`, `/^(.{27})/`, `unpack "A27A*"`....

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible to do something like that, and it would have been a pretty cool thing to do. I have already adopted an alternative you can see it in the comments for the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = qr/\s{2,}(?=.{1,27}\s\s+)(?=(?<name>(\S+\s)*\S+))/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    /$re/;
    say /$re/ ? "OK : $_, name=$+{name}" : "KO : $_";
}
__DATA__
aa  12345 67890  bb
aa  12345 678901234 56789012345 678  bb
```

**Output:**

```
OK : aa  12345 67890  bb, name=12345 67890
KO : aa  12345 678901234 56789012345 678  bb
```

Comment: this is something close to what I expected, but it isn't going to work as well as I expected, so I will take the first 27 chars and after that I will calculate the distance to the column, and based on that I will know what column is. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Not sure who downvoted... but I don't find anything wrong with the proposed solution.

Comment: @Jerry: Thank you. And, yes, an explanation would be welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions aren't a panacea for all ills, and they are the wrong choice in this case. You should split your string on multiple space characters, and reject the substrings that are over-length.

This program demonstrates it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $st = '  aaa aa aa  2long 2long 2long 2long 2long  bb bbb bb  cc cc ccc  ';

say for grep { $_ and length $_ <= 27 } split /\s{2,}/, $st;
```

**Output**

```
aaa aa aa
bb bbb bb
cc cc ccc
```